# MySQL Query Passing Two Variables Python SQLConnector

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I can't seem to get two values passed on a query, I can get one variable to pass no problem, can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, error posted when I try to use the two variable code, one variable code passes.

One Variable:

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SELECT `HOME TEAM:` FROM `nbav8` WHERE `HOME TEAM:` is NOT NULL")

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

awayuyu = []
homeuyu = []
kt = "Atlanta"
for team in myresult:
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()

    mycursor.execute("SELECT `ACTUAL OVER UNDER RESULT:` FROM `previous_losses_nbav1_with_date_agg` WHERE `HOME TEAM:` = %s", team)
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    print(myresult)

print(myresult)
```

Two Variable:

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SELECT `HOME TEAM:` FROM `nbav8` WHERE `HOME TEAM:` is NOT NULL")

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

awayuyu = []
homeuyu = []
kt = "Atlanta"
for team in myresult:
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("SELECT `ACTUAL OVER UNDER RESULT:` FROM `previous_losses_nbav1_with_date_agg` WHERE `HOME TEAM:` = %s OR 'AWAY TEAM:' = %s;", team, team)
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    print(myresult)

print(myresult)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/joshb/PycharmProjects/NBA_V8/grabbing_page_data.py", line 26, in <module>
    mycursor.execute("SELECT `ACTUAL OVER UNDER RESULT:` FROM `previous_losses_nbav1_with_date_agg` WHERE `HOME TEAM:` = %s OR 'AWAY TEAM:' = %s;", team, team)
  File "C:\Users\joshb\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 540, in execute
    stmt = RE_PY_PARAM.sub(psub, stmt)
  File "C:\Users\joshb\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 77, in __call__
    raise errors.ProgrammingError(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not enough parameters for the SQL statement
```

Updated code after answer:

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SELECT `HOME TEAM:` FROM `nbav8` WHERE `HOME TEAM:` is NOT NULL")

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
print(myresult)
yeet = 0
awayuyu = []
homeuyu = []
kt = "Atlanta"
temp1 = "Miami"
temp2 = "Toronto"
for team in myresult:
    data1 = team
    data2 = team
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    sql = """SELECT `ACTUAL OVER UNDER RESULT:` FROM `previous_losses_nbav1_with_date_agg` WHERE `HOME TEAM:` = %s OR 'AWAY TEAM:' = %s"""
    mycursor.execute(sql, (data1, data2), multi=True)
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    print(myresult)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/joshb/PycharmProjects/NBA_V8/grabbing_page_data.py", line 28, in <module>
    mycursor.execute(sql, (data1, data2), multi=True,)
  File "C:\Users\joshb\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 539, in execute
    psub = _ParamSubstitutor(self._process_params(params))
  File "C:\Users\joshb\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 421, in _process_params
    raise errors.ProgrammingError(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'tuple' cannot be converted to a MySQL type
```

I am not sure I still get this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place you parameters in a `tuple`, like this:

```py
cursor.execute(sql, (param1, param2))
```

The MySQL Connector [cursor.execute](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) method accepts three parameters: the SQL statement, parameters and a flag (`multi`).  When you execute

```py
cursor.execute(sql, team, team)
```

the final parameter is assumed to be the `multi` flag.  It's best practice to always pass parameter values as a tuple*, even if there is only one (`(param,)`).  You may get other errors otherwise.

---

* You can use a `list` also, but using a `tuple` is conventional.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I updated my question, I believe I am following the correct syntax now but getting an error still.

Comment: My bad - I didn't look hard enough at the preceding code.  `fetchall()` returns a list of tuples, so `SELECT team FROM tbl` will result in `[('TeamA',), ('TeamB',), ... ]`.  So your values parameters should be the first element of each tuple `(team[0], team[0])`.  (Or slightly tricksier, `team + team`, which will merge the two tuples into a single tuple).

Comment: Thanks a ton! This had me stopped for hours, the [0] was the game changer. Appreciate your help.